# Sortablejs and empty groups causing flickering

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, after-effects, sortablejs

I'm developing an extension for After Effects which makes use of drag and drop functions. I'm using sortablejs library but I'm happy to use something else if I can't fix the issue I have.

Check this video here: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/rOYVm2u0zY8

The issue (flickering) appears when a group becomes empty.

The line of code related to sortablejs is

```
Sortable.create(el , {
  animation: 300,
  easing: "cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.56, 0.64, 1)",
  draggable: ".colorButton",
  ghostClass: 'ghost',
  group: {
    name: "sameGroup"
  },
  onEnd: function (evt) {
    
    // my function here

  }
});
```

When a color is moved to a new position the panel reloads and the code above runs again.

The colors are div with float:left
The divs that cointain the colors have a minimum dimension of 34px by 34px, which is the size of one color.

Any help?

I just want to remove the flickering.